# How the Chinese number categorized in Unicode database?

Tags: unicode, numbers

I am learning Unicode now, I list all the code under category 'Decimal Number' 
[Unicode (General_Category=Decimal_Number)](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AGeneral_Category=Decimal_Number%3A%5D)

I have a question as I am a Chinese, I cannot find chinese number under the Decimal Number. I found them categorized as 'Other Letter' 
[一二三四五六七八九十零壹貳叁肆伍陸柒捌玖拾贰陆](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%8C%E4%B8%89%E5%9B%9B%E4%BA%94%E5%85%AD%E4%B8%83%E5%85%AB%E4%B9%9D%E5%8D%81%E9%9B%B6%E5%A3%B9%E8%B2%B3%E5%8F%81%E8%82%86%E4%BC%8D%E9%99%B8%E6%9F%92%E6%8D%8C%E7%8E%96%E6%8B%BE%E8%B4%B0%E9%99%86%0D%0A&g=&i=)

I like to know more, is there any reasons?

Comment: Maybe [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzhou_numerals) helps?

Comment: That's not a programming question. Ask on the [`unicode@unicode.org` mailing list](https://www.unicode.org/consortium/distlist.html).